# How to disable copy/paste from/to SearchView

Tags: android, searchview, android-actionmode

I would like to disable copy/paste actions when I use the `SearchView` in `Toolbar`.

Actually I don't want to have the native copy/past bar which appears on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void disableSearchViewActionMode(SearchView searchView) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        ((EditText) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text)).setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```